# How to connect the connect to a PiHUB?

Tags: power-supply, usb-power, connection

I just got my PiHUB but there are no instructions on how to use it :(

I need:

1. To connect it to 3 USB devices,
2. The USB devices need to be controlled by 1 Rpi,
3. That Rpi would (preferably) be powered by the PiHub too.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming this is the PiHub shaped like a Raspberry (pictured).

You should find that the hub has four normal USB (type A) ports, a socket for the power cable and another port (which is a USB type B port). The type B port is pictured here - it's the middle one:
[image: Picture of Pi Hub]

You should have a cable that plugs into the type B port. Plug it in and then connect the other end (the flat USB end) into your Pi. This ensures that whatever else you plug into the hub sends it's data to the Pi.

Now, you should be left with 4 normal USB ports. Turn the Hub over. One of the USB ports has the Raspberry Pi logo next to it. Connect a cable from that port to the power socket of your Pi - so that's a USB type A plug on the hub to the micro USB power port for your Pi.

That's got everything you *need* connected up. You're then left with three other type A USB ports to plug in peripherals, like keyboard, mouse etc.